# Get index of clicked element using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, indexing, onclick

I need to know the index of clicked element. Can't figure out how to do it

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('my_div').children.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('my_div').children[i].onclick = function(){'ALERT POSITION OF CLICKED CHILD'};
}
```

this.index?

here is a example of what I am trying to do (it only gives back 6):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{margin:0;}
#container div{height:50px;line-height:50px; text-align:center}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
</div>
<script>
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('container').children.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('container').children[i].onclick = function(){alert('Number ' + i + ' was clicked')};
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is a [piece of code](http://jsfiddle.net/gffwse8q/) that can help you get the index of the clicked element inside the `for` loop. All you need is a new [scope](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html):

```
var g = document.getElementById('my_div');
for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
{

    (function(index){
        g.children[i].onclick = function(){
              alert(index)  ;
        }    
    })(i);

}
```

**Edit 1:** Incorporating user Felix Kling's comments into the answer.

> event handler already is a closure

**Edit 2:** Updated fiddle link

Comment: Strictly speaking the event handler already **is** a closure. What the OP needed was a new scope.

Comment: Any idea why the code may be failing to show any output? I tried both Safari and Google.

Comment: @rohan-patel That is odd. Here is a newer fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gffwse8q/ (tested in Chrome and Safari).

Comment: Thanks for the update! Not sure why it was broken. Maybe version change?

Comment: See my second answer on this page, this solution is far for optimal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801787/get-index-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript/48680284#48680284

Answer (score 57):

With ES6 destructuring you can do

```
const index = [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el)
```

or

```
const index = Array.from(el.parentElement.children).indexOf(el)
```

or ES5 version

```
var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.parentElement.children).indexOf(el)
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer (from Ashwin Krishnamurthy) is actually far from optimal.

You can just do:

```
const g = document.getElementById('my_div');
for (let i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
{
    g.children[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(index)  ;
    }
}
```

to avoid creating unnecessary closures. And even then it's not optimal since you're creating 6 DOM event handlers (6 `divs` in the example above) just to get a number of a single clicked `div`.

What you should actually do is use an event delegation (attach **single** click event to the parent) and then check the `e.target`'s index using the method I've mentioned earlier and above ([Get index of clicked element using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801787/get-index-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript/46328506#46328506)).

Comment: Not sure why this has -1 since it's better solution than any mentioned here ;)

Comment: it just doesn't work. have you even tried running it?

Comment: At present I think this is the best answer. Since we have the option to use 'let' to keep 'i' local in scope, in this case it's superior to 'var' and we don't need to write the anon self invoking function to define our own local variable. Just change it to 'alert(i)' not alert(index) since index is not defined in your code @MelkorNemesis

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue where I needed to loop through an array and get the index number of the item clicked.

Here is how I solved the issue...

```
//first store array in a variable
let container = [...document.getElementById('container')];

//loop through array with forEach function
container.forEach((item,index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(index));
});
```

This will console.log the index number of the item clicked on.

Hope this answers some questions.

Comment: When you are using a `forEach`, you don't need to do `container.indexOf`. Just change your `forEach(item => {` syntax to `forEach((item, index) => {` and you have the `index` !!

Answer (score 5):

I made a function to find the index.

```js
function getElementIndex(el) {
  return [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el);
}
```

Call it like this:

```js
const index = getElementIndex(element);
```

Answer (score 2):

Table cell elements have a `cellIndex` property, but I don't know about other elements. You will either have to

- create a closure to reserve the value of `i`
- dynamically count `previousSibling`s
- add an `index` property in your for-loop and read that (don't augment host objects).

The closure approach will be the easiest, I think. Please make sure you have understood how closures work, there are good explanations on the web.

```
function makeAlertNumber(element, i) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
       alert('Number ' + i + ' was clicked');
    }, false);
}
[].slice.call(document.getElementById('container').children).forEach(makeAlertNumber); // homework: find a way to express this for older browsers :-)
```

Comment: THanks Bergi, would you like to show an example in the code I added?

Answer (score 1):

The index in relationship to what ?

If it is about the index within the current HTML collection, the index would just be represented with your `i` counter variable.

One word of caution: Since HTMLCollections are "Live", you should ever use them to figure out the `.length` within a loop. If it happens to be that those elements are added or removed within the loop, strange and dangerous things can happen. Cache the `.length` value before calling the loop instead.

Comment: @david: indeed. Totally forgot about this fact :)

Comment: Thanks jAndy. The index related to the other children. Added a example if you want to have a look

Comment: You could also simply loop over the elements in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++){
      (function(index){
        childNodes[i].addEventListener("click", myScript);
        function myScript(){
          console.log(index);
        }
      })(i);
    }
```

Comment: If you are using `let`, you don’t need the IIFE.

Answer (score 0):

`getIndexOfNode: function(node){
            var i = 1;
            while(node.previousElementSibling != null){
                i++
            }
            return i;
        }`

the function will return the index of the node passed in its parent element.

Comment: `node` never changes, so this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
getIndexOfNode = function(node){
    var i = 1;
    while(node.previousElementSibling != null){
      node = node.previousElementSibling;
        i++
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 