# Determine the .length index of the <li> item clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a set of `<li>` items:

```
<ul id="listings">
<li id="item-0">
  <div class="content">hi</div>
<li>
<li id="item-1">
  <div class="content">hi</div>
<li>
<li id="item-2">
  <div class="content">hi</div>
<li>
</ul>
//etc
```

**My question is: How do I determine the index number of the clicked `<li>` item?**.
Like if I click: `<li id="item-1">` I want to know it's the second `<li>` index.

I can easily determine the total lenght of all `<li>`'s by doing:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#listings li').length;
```

And I currently have the following click listener:

```
document.getElementById("listings").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        console.log(e.target.id + " was clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: So you're saying that their `id` attributes won't always be in the correct order? Otherwise, you could just use string manipulation to extract the number from the `id`.

Comment: yea thought of that - but cant rely on the id order :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801787/get-index-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="listings">
  <li id="item-0" onclick="isClicked(0)">
    <div class="content">hi</div>
  </li>
  <li id="item-1" onclick="isClicked(1)">
    <div class="content">hi</div>
  </li>
  <li id="item-2" onclick="isClicked(2)">
    <div class="content">hi</div>
  </li>
//...
```

I would add an onclick function to the li. Using javascript you can collect the data.

```
function isClicked(number){
   alert("Clicked element: "+ number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ulLength = document.getElementById('listings');
var elements = [].slice.call(ulLength.childNodes);
//[].slice.call() is used to convert array-like objects/collections into an array

function getSiblings() {
    var _s = [];
    elements.forEach(function (i, d) {
        if (i.nodeType === 1) //prevents text nodes to be counted as siblings
        _s.push(i);
    });

    return _s;
}

function getElmIndex(elm) {
    var _siblings = getSiblings();
    for (var i = 0; i < _siblings.length; i++) {
        if (!(_siblings[i] && _siblings[i] !== elm)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

elements.forEach(function (elm, d) {
    elm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var _index = getElmIndex(this);

        alert("Index: " + _index);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/P3M6s/4/)

Comment: Hi Tarun Pai - thanks for contributing. It seems if any html elements are added to the <li> (like a <div>) then the click will turn up undefined. Can that be taken into account with the above functions?

Comment: Well you can change that by altering the `node` variable, but it'll behave more like a hack; will need some time to build a generic solution.

Comment: @user1231561 if it's not mandatory for you to attach the event to the `ul#listings` it get's easier.

Answer (score -2):

If using Jquery is not a problem, I suggest the use of the `index()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/JLkPs/ .

Source: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: ill have a look at this if all other fails - currently no Jquery is used. But thanks anyways

Comment: Jquery is a **bloated** solution for a problem such as this.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/172936

Comment: @Lix can you explain why or you pass your evening downvoting answers? It's a solution, probably the most elegant you can find if you can use Jquery. IF, as in the answer.

Comment: @LorenzoS - including an additional library for something like this is most certainly **not** the most elegant way. I pass my evenings browsing [so] and casting votes according to their contribution and future value.

Comment: I appreciate that you're just trying to help here. But I really feel like this answer does more harm than good to the internet as a whole. The moto for [so] is "make the internet a better place".

Comment: Answers should be relevant to the question. The question has nothing to do with jQuery. We could clutter this question with 50 different answers for 50 different libraries, or we could simply answer the question.

Comment: [last reply] Nowhere is suggested to add an additional library just to do this, it's your assumption. The answer starts with an "IF", and the rest of the answer is a solution for the question. Enjoy your downvoting hobby.

Comment: If you have a question about the criteria, then you should post a comment for the OP to clarify. Otherwise again, we could bombard the user with 50 answers he won't find useful, but that are all *technically* correct *if* some condition is met. Answers should be directly on-topic. There's no need to be bitter about it.