# JS: Feeding indexes of an array into their own onclick functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object-literal

I'm a tyro. I've hunted around and found answers to similar questions, but implementing their solutions (probably incorrectly) I haven't continuously failed at this. I making my own "Conrad's Game of Life." I have cells that are placed into an array "allCells", of size "worldSize" (which is a variable determined by the user before commencing the "game").

These cells are all Object Literals with various attributes, one of which is their "domInfo", which equals a "div" with a given class name.

I assign the cells all of their properties in a for loop. In that for loop, I want something that functions like this (seems it ought to):

```
    allCells[i].domInfo.onclick = userFlipsStatusOfCell(i);
```

userFlipsStatusOfCell is a function that checks the status of the cell (dead or alive) and flips it. It requires the index of the cell in the array.

Secondary question: would changing the cells to a Cell Class and creating a prototype function solve this somehow?

EDIT: pseudo-duplicate (this similar solution lacking the "return" didn't work for me when I tried it), also other good information available here: [Get index of clicked element using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801787/get-index-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript/8802111#8802111)

Comment: You are calling the function and assigning the result, not assigning the function itself.

Comment: Doing `allCells[i].domInfo.onclick = userFlipsStatusOfCell(i);` will assign the return value of that function into the onclick property. You instead need to assign the function itself.

Comment: Excellent education for me. Thanks everyone. Gonna play with this concept until it sticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function and assigning the result, not assigning the function. You might be tempted to do:

```
allCells[i].domInfo.onclick = function(){userFlipsStatusOfCell(i)};
```

however that will keep *i* in a closure so all the listeners will get the same value (the last value that *i* was set to before exiting the loop). To prevent that, one option is:

```
allCells[i].domInfo.onclick = (function(n) {
                                 return function(){userFlipsStatusOfCell(n)};
                              }(i));
```

Comment: I now have a working "game of life". Thank you. This answer almost verbatim is out there somewhere, it didn't work for me. They didn't use "return", and perhaps that's the difference. If I find that answer again, I'll link it here.