# How to make this div clickable?

Tags: javascript, css

I wanto to make each "card" of this wordpress plugin clickable (http://www.davidbo.dreamhosters.com/?page_id=11)

So I added a Pure JS element with the following code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fc_card-container').onclick = function() {alert('It works!');}
```

and it is not working so I wonder how wrong this is.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply a click event handler for all the cards:

```
// Get all the elements with a .fc_card-container class and store them on a variable
// .getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object with all the selected elements 
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('fc_card-container');

// Use [].slice.apply(cards) to convert the cards NodeList into an array
// Iterate over the cards array with a .forEach

[].slice.apply(cards).forEach(function(card, index){ 

    // Each array element corresponds to a card element
    // Use the .addEventListener( EVENT, callback ) to attach an event handler for each card element

    card.addEventListener("click", function(e){ 
        alert(); 
        console.log(cards[index]); // Index gives us the exact array position (index) of the clicked card. 
        console.log(e.target); // e.target gives us access to the clicked element
    }); 

});
```

Comment: While this would produce the result the OP is looking for, I'm confident the OP wouldn't be able to follow this answer.  You should break down what each piece does.

Comment: You're right. I've added some comments that might help. Let me know If the code needs some more clarification.

Comment: How would you get the box identity inside addEventListener like in number(first box, second box)?

Comment: The index variable denotes the number of the clicked card among the cards array.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of matched elements. In your case, an array of elements with the class name of `fc_card-container`. Your next step would be to iterate over the elements and assign an event listener to each or select a specific one using an index (starting with 0).

## Assign a click to all

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('fc_card-container');
for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){ //iterate through each card
   cards[i].onclick = function() {alert('It works!');};
};
```

## Assign a click to a single card (eg: 3rd card)

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('fc_card-container');
cards[2].onclick = function() {alert('It works!');}; //0,1,2
```

Comment: I've added code value of 'i' variable in alert('It works!' + i) but 'i' variable always get count of div classes found. How can I get exactly the box number, which it has clicked

Comment: That's because that's the final number that i becomes at the end of the loop.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801787/get-index-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript