# On click of any button should display the correct number for that button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new to JavaScript, I want to display the value of my buttons when I click on it. Every Button got different numbers so I am not sure how can I display their values in console.

Here is my HTML code.

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">5</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">6</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This is possibly the same scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801787/get-index-of-clicked-element-using-pure-javascript

Comment: @all why did you guys mark it negative since I tried...but got stuck

Comment: @texirv Do not take downvotes personally - especially at this stage where you have no points to lose. SO is designed for more specific programming questions than you ask, but all of us started where you are now and many of us are understanding. Do not let the few "itchy trigger fingers" discourage you. Continue to ask questions. Ask often. Ask lots. Learn, and contribute. For those answering questions, SO is all about getting "points" - so (as soon as you have 15 points) upvote any answer that is helpful to you in any way -- and always accept the best answer (green checkmark).  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

**myFunction()** is called by `onclick(event){...}` which has `event` as argument.
WebKit follows IE's old behavior of passing `event`, into handler functions.
So in `webkit` and `IE` you  can access `event` inside `myFunction` to get the `event.target`.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
  }
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">5</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">6</button>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

But **Firefox** isn't passing the event into `handler functions`, so you can achieve your goal by editing `myFunction()` to receive argument `this` in `html` (`this` will refer to the `current HTML element`).

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">5</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">6</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve using closures :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```js
function showNum(){
  var wew = $(this).text();
  console.log(wew)
  $('#demo').text(wew);
}

$('.btn').on('click', showNum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
3. Test on JavaScript Closures - for loop with 5 Buttons. On click of any button should display the correct number for that button (Important). 

    <button class="btn">1</button>
    <button class="btn">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button>
    <button class="btn">4</button>
    <button class="btn">5</button>
    <button class="btn">6</button>


    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: any idea how to achieve with closure :(

Comment: check the new code

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, this may help you:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7tkm157/2/)

```
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">1</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">2</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">3</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">4</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">5</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">6</button>


    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      function myFunction(element) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        console.log(element.innerHTML)
      }

    </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: any idea how to achieve with closure :(