# javascript onclick event not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this click event attached to each button and when I click on each of them, it is printing the output meant for the third button. I'm not sure what is going on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>test1</button>
  <button>test2</button>
  <button>test3</button>
</body>
<script>
   var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
       nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log('You clicked element #' + i);
   });
   }
</script>
</html>
```

when I click on any of the buttons, it is printing

```
"You clicked element #3"
```

Comment: When `click` fires, it shows the last value of `i`, which is 3. You need to use closure here. Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/a/8802111/3639582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button>test1</button>
    <button>test2</button>
    <button>test3</button>
</body>
<script>
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    console.log(nodes);
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        //converted click function into an IIFE so it executes then and there only
        nodes[i].addEventListener('click', (function (j) {
            return function () {
                console.log('You clicked element #' + j);
            }

        })(i));
    }
</script>

</html>
```

You should go through two concepts to understand this thing

1) Closures

2) Javascript is single-threaded and synchronous. So how does it handle events?

Here is what it is happening in your code:

==> for loop gets executed synchronously as it is part of javascript engine post which javascript handles event queue which is a FIFO (first in first out)

==> When for loop finished value of i is three which remains in memory until the function inside it executes

==> Each time it takes a value 3 and prints it.

Comment: I invited you to chat

Answer (score 1):

This is the closure with function inside a loop issue.

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Watch out for this!

Side note: questions around this issue are frequently asked in interviews to demonstrate proficiency with JS.

Answer (score 1):

When this `button` is listening to event, at that time the value of `i` is `nodes.length` -1 that is `2`. Because loop has already finished it's execution and have set value of `i` to 2.

So it is consoling `You clicked element #3`.

Such issues arise because of `scope` & `closure`

Create an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and pass the value of `i`.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
  var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
   for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
   (function(i){
   nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log('You clicked element #' + i);
   });
}(i))

   }
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxsqu70t/1/)

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what is the problem in my case? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is other way using jQuery.

```
$("button").each(function(e) {
    $(this).data("number", e);
}).bind("click", function(e) {
    console.log("You clicked element #" + $(this).data("number"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChaHyukIm/uxsqu70t/3/